# HTML Code to Trigger Download on a Webpage

Tags: html, excel, button, download

I'm trying to write a program that does the following in HTML.

Creates a button that links to a webpage. Inside the webpage there is a button that triggers an Excel file download.

I'd like my code to open the link and download the file in one click.

P.S. I already created the button that opens webpage.

Open to other language solutions.

Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask]

Answer (score 0):

I have created this for you. I have tested it as well.

> ```
>  <a href="location-to-your-excel.xls">
>       <button>
>         ButtonName
>       </button>
>  </a>
> ```

You need to put your excel file in the project folder also.
Hope it helps! Cheers from Hungary.